# mysql subqueries or join

Tags: mysql, linux

I have 5 tables in my Mysql database with t1 with field name like data,id,cool and 4 other tables with id and data say t2,t3,t4,t5.

I have used join and sub queries  but result i am getting is empty set its not mandatory that all the fields in the t2,t3,t4,t5 tables are populated .t4,t5,t3,t2 can be empty i am using where clause  on data if data column of t1 = t2 = t3 = t4 = t5 if it finds any matching data in any of the table it prints the cool from t1 and id and data from found table if any and if founds the data match in all the table it prints all the table stats like

```
cool data.t1 id.t1
cool data.t2 id.t2 
and so on



table t1

cool data id
0    xyz   1

table t2

data id
xyz   5

table t3

data id
xyz   4

table t4

data id
xyz   3

table t5

data id
xyz   2
```

desired output

```
cool data id
  0   xyz  1
  0   xyz  4
  0   xyz  3
  0   xyz  5
  0   xyz  2
```

if any of the table is empty say  t5 and t4 than output should be

```
 cool data id
  0   xyz  1
  0   xyz  4
  0   xyz  3
```

Comment: Your question is very poorly worded - can you please rephrase it .. perhaps include a sample of data

Comment: Also, a few fulls stops would surely help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i understand from the question is you need to get data from table `t1` for all other tables for all matching `data` and `id` column in respective table.

A simple way to achieve is to join each table with `t1` seperately and then use `union all` to combine all results.

```
SELECT t1.cool, t2.data, t2.id
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON (t1.id=t2.id) AND (t1.data=t2.data)
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.cool, t3.data, t3.id
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t3 ON (t1.id=t3.id) AND (t1.data=t3.data)
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.cool, t4.data, t4.id
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t4 ON (t1.id=t4.id) AND (t1.data=t4.data)
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.cool, t5.data, t5.id
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t5 ON (t1.id=t5.id) AND (t1.data=t5.data)
```

---

as from your example, it is quite possible that there can be duplicate records To filter them out use distinct like this -

```
SELECT DISTINCT cool, data, id
FROM
(
-- above query here
)
```